# Class <?> cls = Class.forname("java.util.ArrayList");

Tags: java, generics

Разбирая чужой код, наткнулся на такую строчку

```
Class <?> cls = Class.forname("java.util.ArrayList");
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает знак вопроса в скобках, и что это, подгружает что-то из класса `ArrayList`?

Comment: Знак вопроса указывает на неграмотность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `<?>` - короткая версия для `<? extends Object>`, так называемые [Unbounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html). Позволяет задавать любой тип дженерику.

   `Class<?>` обозначает, что `cls` может быть любого типа.

   По возможности лучше избегать такого кода, так как он может привести ко множеству проблем.
2. [`Class.forname`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) же возвращает класс по имени, чтоб потом, к примеру, можно было создать его экземпляр `cls.newInstance();`